# localeCompare array of objects sorting not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My issue similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49305811/sort-of-array-of-objects-not-working), but not the same.

I'm trying to sort an array of objects using `localeCompare`. It has no reason not to work, but it's not working. Somehow I'm doing something right./sigh/

This is how I fetch the data

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isBusy, setBusy] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('I was run once');
    async function fetchData() {
      const url = `${
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE
        }/api/v1/endpoint/`;

      axios.get(url).then((response: any) => {
        setBusy(false);
        setData(response.data.results)
        console.log(response.data.results);
      });
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [])
```

This is the sorting function

```
  function onSort(event: any, sortKey: string) {
    const newData = data;
    newData.sort((a: any, b: any): any => {
      a[sortKey].toString().localeCompare(b[sortKey]);
    })
    setData(newData);
  }
```

A typical array of objects is like this

```
[
  {
    "avatar": "big",
    "name": "Username",
  },
  {
    "avatar": "small",
    "name": "Rex",
  },
  {
    "avatar": "medium",
    "name": "Duh",
  }
]
```

Then the table header has this

```
<th scope="col" className="text-center" onClick={e => onSort(e, 'name')}>Name</th>
```

Although the `onSort()` function runs without any errors, the objects don't get sorted as per the `sortKey`

Am I using the `localeCompare` wrongly? What can I do to make the above right?

Also, the `setData`, I believe should update the `data` and thus trigger a rebuild of the table, which seems to be happening, because if I pass in an empty array to the `setData`, the table blanks.

**edit:**

The HTML part

```
              ...
              return (
                <div>
                  <table className="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th onClick={e => onSort(e, 'avatar')}>Avatar</th>
                        <th onClick={e => onSort(e, 'name')}>Name</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {data && data.map((item: any, index: any) => {
                        return (
                          <tr key={index}>
                            <th>{{ item.avatar}}</th>
                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                            <td className="text-center" style={{ 'fontSize': '32px', 'color': '#981c1e' }}>0</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                      })}

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                 </div>
              ...
```

If I understand, if the `setData` triggers a data change, the `render` re-renders?

Comment: See the [linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value), your arrow function has no return value. Either `newData.sort((a: any, b: any): any => {
      return a[sortKey].toString().localeCompare(b[sortKey]);
    })` (added `return`) or `newData.sort((a: any, b: any): any => a[sortKey].toString().localeCompare(b[sortKey]))` (no `{}`).

Comment: You can't set state with a mutated version because React [won't render](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutate-state-bad-t264j)  You should do: `const newData = [...data];`

Comment: @HMR You're right. That's the solution.

Answer (score 5):

You need a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) by using curly brackets in an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
newData.sort((a: any, b: any): any => {
    return a[sortKey].toString().localeCompare(b[sortKey]);
});
```

Comment: There's a [well-established dupetarget for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754957/why-doesnt-my-arrow-function-return-a-value).

Comment: It might appear as the lack of `return` being the problem, but it's not. With return doesn't still update.

Comment: @KhoPhi, you need to update the html part as well after sorting.

Comment: @NinaScholz Updated with HTML. To my understanding, that re-rendering is automatically taken care of, if `setData` is triggered, no?

Comment: i don't know react.